# What is the lowest entropy per particle possible in a material?

Tags: thermodynamics, statistical-mechanics

For normal materials (not for fermion condensates or  Bose-Einstein condensates) one finds tables giving entropy per particle.

For diamond at room temperature, this seems to be 0.29 k.

Is there a theoretical minimum? (It seems that in degenerate systems, the value can be as low as desired. But is it also the case for non-degenerate systems?)

One reason for the question is that the Sackur-Tetrode equation seems to point to 3k/2; but experimental values for solids are lower. How does this fit together?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This question can basically be rephrased as: "Is there an upper limit on the Debye temperature?"

The [Debye model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Debye_model) is typically a good approximation for the heat capacity $C_V(T)$ of a crystalline solid ($T_{\rm D}$ is the Debye temperature):

$$\frac{C_V(T)}{N k_{\rm B}} = 9 {\left(\frac{T}{T_{\rm D}}\right)}^3 \int_0^{T_{\rm D}/T}{\rm d}x\frac{x^4\exp(x)}{(\exp(x)-1)^2}$$

The integral cannot be computed analytically. The result of numerical quadrature is shown below:

[image: Heat capacity according to Debye model.]

For low temperatures, $C_V/(N k_{\rm})$ is proportional to $T^3$, for large temperatures it becomes 3 ([Dulong-Petit law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dulong%E2%80%93Petit_law)). The value of three here is related to an equipartition of energy for the degrees of freedom per lattice site in the solid. The Sackur-Tetrode equation for the monoatomic gas entropy mentioned by the OP also corresponds to an equipartion of energy, but this is as far as the analogy goes here. To calculate the entropy of a solid according to the Debye model, the integral

$$S(T) = \int_0^T \frac{{\rm d}T'}{T'}C_V(T')$$

needs to be evaluated. The corresponding entropy is plotted below at a temperature of 300 K and as a function of the Debye temperature $T_D$:

[image: Entropy according to Debye model.]

The entropy decreases monotonically with $T_D$. The dashed line indicates the Debye temperature of diamond: the Debye model yields an entropy value relatively close to the measured value the OP found in literature.

For infinite $T_D$, the entropy would vanish. But this only accounts for the lattice contribution to entropy. So even if there is no upper bound on the highest phonon energy in a material and thus the Debye temperature, other small entropy terms will remain. For metals, e.g., one can approximate the electronic heat capacity to be linear in $T$, and inversely proportional to the Fermi temperature $T_F$ ([link to Wikipedia article on electronic specific heat](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electronic_specific_heat)). Integrating the electronic specific heat according to the equation for $S$ above, one finds that the entropy will decrease with the Fermi temperature:

[image: Electronic entropy as a function of Fermi temperature.]

Again, probably no theoretical upper bound on the Fermi temperature either, but real materials will only have bonds up to a certain strength and thus have a certain hardness and Debye temperature, and also the number of electrons per nucleus is limited for any nucleus with an appreciable lifetime as is the density of real materials and thus the Fermi temperature.

Good references for heat capacity models are the solid state textbooks by Kittel or Ashcroft and Mermin.

Comment: Minor comment on this excellent answer: you have written “monotonous” when you meant “monotonic.”

Comment: Indeed! The Debye model is not boring :)

Answer (score 1):

> One reason for the question is that the Sackur-Tetrode equation seems to point to 3k/2; but experimental values for solids are lower. How does this fit together?

The Sackur-Tetrode equation hold for ideal gasses, in which molecules move through the whole volume. Molecules in "normal" solids are localized, meaning that they are oscillating around equilibrium positions. Therefore, I would expect the entropic contribution linked to the spatial degrees of freedom to be lower in solids than in gasses.

Note that if the solid is perfectly regular and the positions of the molecules are perfectly static, then the spatial contribution to the entropy is zero.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, (perfectly) crystalline solids have no configurational entropy: this is because each atom is distinguishable from the others through its lattice position and this is also why you can't apply Sackur Tetrode equation to solids (as already pointed out by [Javi](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/701805)).

Additionally, in some materials (in particular in very stiff materials) some degrees of freedom for the momentum are also "frozen" in the sense that oscillations in certain directions are heavily suppressed at low temperatures, similarly to what happens to biatomic gas molecules at low temperature. In crystals this obviously depends on the strength of the bonds and on the lattice structure. Moreover, even if some oscillations are not suppressed, they can not happen independently of other atoms, so that neighbouring atoms are effectively sharing some degrees of freedom.

Now, the degrees of freedom argument is a bit heuristic, but the point is that everything depends strongly on the type of bonds between atoms. For instance one can easily build a model in which interatomic bonds are so strong that at low temperature the energy thoroughly goes into the oscillation of the entire crystal (while keeping all the interatomic distances unchnaged). In such a case the entropy per particle can go arbitrarily close to $0$ (by increasing the number of atoms of the crystal).

This would show that there is no such thing as "theoretical minimum". Then obviously one can check that no "normal" material with such a property exists, but "in theory" there's nothing excluding such possibility.

Comment: Thank you. Is there some book or paper where one can read more about this?